# How can i call a function after close an intent of web browser?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I build a non-activity class and in this class , need to open a web browser in my app for login and the web page close automatically after login so i want call a function after close the web browser .
no problem on opening web browser.

```
public class DIDCore {
long appdid;
.
.
.
Activity myactivity;}
public DIDCore(long APPDID,Activity activity){      
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    appdid=APPDID;
    myactivity=activity;
}
public void LoginDID(){                             
    try {
    ....
    ....
       Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www......com/login.aspx?code=110"));                  
            myactivity.startActivityForResult(browserIntent, 1);
    }
```

but i can't check when close the intent

so i need to your help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you are starting the activity with the use of myactivity object

so when you close the webview activity autometically your myactivity's

```
 onActivityResult()
```

method will be call , so you can do your process here....

or else try to call browser activity within other activity instead of normal class

Comment: how can i override the onactivityresult() method in DIDCore class

Comment: you can't override onActivityResult() in your DIDCore class. just create one static method in DIDCore class and call this method in your myactivity's onActivityResult() ,so when the WebActivity closed onActivityResult() will call and it will call the DIDCore static method

Comment: you right
but i most check in DIDCore because DIDCore is Main Class
and another developer will use DIDCore so LoginDID method most open web browser and login and after closing the web browser most call a protected mothod for check true login so i can't do this from myactivity.
DIDCore work independent
Perhaps I could not say what's my means
tnx for your help